# How to redirect traffic for a Firebase Function to another region when current one goes down?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Suppose I have a callable function that is deployed to multiple regions.

My client side app does not specify region(but default is `us-central1`), so in the event where the default region goes down, does Firebase/Google Cloud automatically redirect traffic to other regions that are up?

If that wasn't the case, what to do in such scenarios?

I'm sure there's something, but my search attempts haven't reached anything.

Answer (score 1):

No, each Cloud Function deployed has its own URL that also includes the region and requests would be routed to that function only. Cloud Functions don't have a load balancer like functionality by default. If number of requests rises, Cloud Functions will just create new instances to handle them.

You can check user's location, find the nearest GCP region where your function is deployed and call that. That should also reduce latency a bit and balance the requests based on user region.

Alternatively, if you want to ensure requests are handled by functions in same regions, also checkout [Global external HTTP(S) load balancer with Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#set_up_regional_routing).

Comment: Does regional routing require a load-balancer for each function or would one be able to handle all functions(around 200) with say 3 regions? Also, what about client-side apps that use the functions; for example an Angular app calls the function by just specifying it's name, how would using a load balancer change that? I think we're looking at a complete refactor away from Firebase SDK to another fetcher just to specify the full URL, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @OmarDulaimi a single load balancer should do. You'll just have to configure the URLs once. It might be easier to follow approach one by using a IP to location API and then setting nearest region to Firebase SDK. If you go for load balancing, then you'll have to follow [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) to call a "Callable Function" using fetch or Axios like libraries as if you are using `onRequest()` functions.
Again,  Cloud Function scale well based on load so load balancing is not really relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the first approach might be the one. But I'm not sure if there's a reliable programmatic way to find if a region is down. Also, I thought about another approach that involves using Runtime Config to set the region value, and fetch it once or twice per hour, but I fear that might hit quota limits.

Comment: @OmarDulaimi there are many ways like IP to location services or maybe read user's timezone and get region (it should be doable storing some JSON object  containing timezone to country data along with a country to region mapping)?

Comment: That is doable for sure. I was just wondering if there was a way to check if a certain region is down/unreachable so I could to switch to another though.

Comment: @OmarDulaimi came across a similar question to yours. My answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75112435/13130697) might help.